# Applying border to image shape

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, border

In my application I am having various images of different different shapes. Like tree, cloud. (Sample image is attached).
I want to add border to those shapes pro-grammatically. Like if image is of tree  then need to highlight tree shape.
I cannot use calayer as it will apply border to UIImageView.
Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

[image: sample image]

Comment: Draw the image twice, first with a scale applied. Masking if the images aren't transparent (but are black&white).

Comment: you want border alway or selected mode

Comment: i want to border always with random color.

Comment: @Wain: Thanks for you reply. I did exactly as you said i merged two images to get single image with border :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple option is to draw the image twice, first with a small scale applied to grow the image a little. Masking if the images aren't transparent (but are black&white).

Comment: This is elegant, but the problem is that the border will not be the same throughout the shape. It will be smaller closer towards the center. The edge detection answer is probably more promising though computationally more complex.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for your feedback but my shape is not constant or same.
It can be tree, polygon, square, umbrella anything so please let me know is there any generic solution for this as shape can be any.

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora That was my point. That's why I though that this enticingly simple solution would not work for you.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved this by using a series of CIFilters. [See images corresponding to steps below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMxbi.jpg). In my example *base image* is a color image with transparent background and *mask* is black and white.

1. Use `CIEdges` to detect edges from the mask.
2. Then make edges thicker by applying disk maximum filter (`CIMorphologyMaximum`).
3. Convert borders image from black-and-white to transparent-and-white with `CIMaskToAlpha`
4. Overlay original image on top of borders.

Full code below:

```swift
let base = CIImage(cgImage: baseImage.cgImage!)
let mask = CIImage(cgImage: maskImage.cgImage!)
        
// 1
let edges = mask.applyingFilter("CIEdges", parameters: [
   kCIInputIntensityKey: 1.0
])
    
// 2    
let borderWidth = 0.02 * min(baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height)
let wideEdges = edges.applyingFilter("CIMorphologyMaximum", parameters: [
    kCIInputRadiusKey: borderWidth
])
        
// 3
let background = wideEdges.applyingFilter("CIMaskToAlpha")
      
// 4  
let composited = base.composited(over: background)
        
// Convert back to UIImage
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
let cgImageRef = context.createCGImage(composited, from: composited.extent)!
return UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef)
```

Comment: What if I want to apply a inner border?

Comment: @DanielZanchi I would overlay the border on top of base image, and then mask it to remove the outer half the border.

Comment: @nikstar awesome solution! how can the outline color be changed to eg. black?

Answer (score 2):

I just did the same thing but with a white border.  I created a mask with a white body and 4px black stroke around the outside to give me the uniform border I want around my target image.  The followng takes advantage of Core Image filters to mask off a solid color background (to be used as the border) and then to mask off and composite the target image.

```
// The two-tone mask image
UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Mask"];

// Create a filler image of whatever color we want the border to be (in my case white)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(maskImage.size, NO, maskImage.scale);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height));
UIImage *whiteImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Use CoreImage to mask the colored background to the mask (the entire opaque region of the mask)
CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions: nil];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIBlendWithAlphaMask"];
[filter setValue: [CIImage imageWithCGImage: whiteImage.CGImage]
          forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue: [CIImage imageWithCGImage: maskImage.CGImage]
          forKey: kCIInputMaskImageKey];

CIImage *whiteBackground = filter.outputImage;

// scale the target image to the size of the mask (accounting for image scale) 
// ** Uses NYXImageKit
image = [image scaleToSize: CGSizeMake(maskImage.size.width * maskImage.scale, maskImage.size.height * maskImage.scale)
                 usingMode: NYXResizeModeAspectFill];

 // finally use Core Image to create our image using the masked white from above for our border and the inner (white) area of our mask image to mask the target image before compositing
 filter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIBlendWithMask"];
 [filter setValue: [CIImage imageWithCGImage: image.CGImage]
           forKey: kCIInputImageKey];
 [filter setValue: whiteBackground
           forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
 [filter setValue: [CIImage imageWithCGImage: maskImage.CGImage]
           forKey: kCIInputMaskImageKey];

 image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: [ciContext createCGImage: filter.outputImage
                                                    fromRect: [filter.outputImage extent]]];
```

Comment: Very long shot a few years later, but would you have the complete code snippet with the compositing part as well available somewhere? I'm working on something similar in Swift.

Comment: @EdouardBarbier Sorry.  I haven't been able to locate where that code snippet was from.  What else are you looking to do?  If I remember correctly, that snippet was the full function (minus the declaration and return statement).

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I was trying to better understand where you set the 4px stroke on the mask and then how the compositing works. (I'm very new to CoreImage). My end goal is to be able to outline png stickers with a border that can vary in tickness.

Comment: It's a bit of good news, bad news.  I found the project where I used this.  My mask was a circle so I ended up changing the code to draw the image within a bezier path that I created using `bezierPathWithRoundedRect` with radius 1/2 image diameter.  Having a path makes it easy to stroke for a consistent border.  Is your mask always the same?  If so, define it as a bezier path – you can hard code coordinates, using basic shapes, or import from SVG.  Paths make things way easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply border to objects present in the image using OpenCV framework.

Check this link. Here edges are detected of an image and border is applied to it. I hope this will give exact idea which you want.

https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial

Comment: Thanks but it not the exact as I want.