# Border is not showing with BezierPath in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I draw image with Bezier Path as follow:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.borderWidth = 2;
    [_round1.layer setMask:shapeLayer];
```

**Problem**

I can not able to see border with that image.

I already tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17408397/2526811)
but with this shape is weird & image is also not set.

Thank you,

Comment: You need two shape layers, one for the mask (without any border) and one that is added as a sublayer with the border. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24770675/1271826 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/22473181/1271826 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/22473181/1271826.

Comment: @Rob, Thanks a lot for your answer! It works!!!  Can you post as an answer so I accept it?

Comment: Really this question is just a duplicate with a very different name, rob shows you 3 duplicates already