# iOS - Algorithm for drawing a border around a bitmap with alpha?

Tags: ios, metal, core-image

First off, no I don't want to use the CoreGraphics properties to accomplish this. It's part of a CoreImage rendering pipeline, so I want to develop this using either an existing CIFilter or writing a custom filter in Metal.

It seems kind of like a convolution operation along the lines of: find the highest alpha value available in the source image within the radius of the outline and set the pixel to that alpha in whatever the outline color is.

This will specifically be used for outlining text, so it can safely be assumed that the source image will have relatively crisp boundaries between opaque and clear pixels.

Comment: Another possibility:
1. Copy the bitmap and fill it with the border color.
2. Blur the filled bitmap.
3. Simple alpha-threshold operation (<0.5 = clear / >0.5 = filled)

Comment: That’s going to involve a lot of computation overhead, as does nikstar’s outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68171790/1271826 with `CIEdges`, `CIMorphologyMaximum`, and `CIMaskToAlpha`. I'd bet that a custom filter would be much faster. I assume it's not an option, but the best would be to outline the text as you prepare the image rather than trying to do it after the fact.

Comment: Could you apply a Sobel operator to the alpha channel and set the border in the color channels based on the Sobel result?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is done with a dilate filter. VImage has one, as does Coregraphics for masks. MPS. Not sure about CI.

For text though, typically one just draws it twice, the first time with a thicker line width.